# Javascript Filter Books by Genre

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

So, I've got a bunch of books, all attached to one or more genres and I've got a filter box (think Amazon) so users can filter through books in their preferred genre.

```
<div class="books">
  <div class="filter"> 
    <ul>
      <li><a class="" data-filter=".classic" href="#">Classic</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="library">
    <li class="book classic">Classic</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm then using a bit of Javascript, so when users select a genre from the filter list, it adds a class of `.hidden` to all books outside that genre.

```
if($('.books').length){
    var books = $('.books');
    books.find('.filter ul a').on('click', function(){
      books.find('.filter ul a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      books.find('.book').addClass('hidden');
      books.find(selector).removeClass('hidden');
      return false;
    });
}
```

I've got a working demo of this in action here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/atImc

Trouble is, I can only search one genre at a time (i.e. Fantasy). I'm not able to select two genres (i.e. Fantasy and Thriller). If anyone could help me to adapt this code to do just that, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Added an All filter to the filter list (thanks to @epascarello for his help on this):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if($('.books').length){
    var books = $('.books');

    books.find('.filter ul a').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      books.find('.filter ul a.all').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');                              
      books.find('.book').addClass('hidden');                  

      books.find('.filter ul a.active').each(                   
        function(){
          var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');       
          books.find(selector).removeClass('hidden');      
        }
      );        
    });

    books.find('.filter ul a.all').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();                                       
      books.find('.filter ul a').removeClass('active');
      books.find('.book').removeClass("hidden");  
      $(this).toggleClass('active');                             
    }); 
  }
});
```

Comment: well look for all of the active elements, not just the one that is selected and do the filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but something like this should work

```
var books = $('.books');
books.find('.filter ul a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();                                  //Cancel the click action
  $(this).toggleClass('active');                       //toggle the active class
  books.find('.book').addClass('hidden');              //hide all of the books
  books.find('.filter ul a.active').each(              //find the selected filters and loop through
      function(){
          var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');  //get the attribute 
          books.find(selector).removeClass('hidden');  //unhide the ones that match
      }
  );      
});
```

Comment: That is fantastic! Thanks for the solution and more importantly the helpful comments.

Comment: Sorry @epascarello, one more question. What would be the best way to set up an "All" filter that resets the filters back every time it is pressed?

Comment: Click that just does: `$('.filter ul a.active').removeClass(".active"); books.removeClass("hidden");`

Comment: I've updated the original question with the "All" filter. It works perfectly, I just want to check I'm doing everything correct? Thanks, again.

Comment: Well you do not remove hidden and the first onclick will apply to the second.