# Javascript Filter Books by Genre and Colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

This is sort of a follow-up to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446357/javascript-filter-books-by-genre/21446453?noredirect=1#comment32362798_21446453) I asked earlier. I want my users to be able to filter books by genre and colour.

It isn't yet working how I intended. When the user selects Horror from genre and Blue from cover colour I want it to show all Horror books that are available in Blue. It's instead just showing all Horror books (regardless of colour) and all blue books (regardless of genre) together.

```
<div class="books">
  <div class="filter">
    <ul class="genre">
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".classic" href="#">Classic</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>

    <ul class="colour">
      <li><a href="#" class="grey" data-filter=".grey" href="#">Grey</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="library">
    <li class="book horror red">Horror<br>in Red</li>
    ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using a bit of Javascript, so when users select a genre or colour from the filter list, it adds a class of .hidden to all books outside that genre or colour.

```
if($('.books').length){
  var books = $('.books');
  books.find('.filter ul a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();                             
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
    books.find('.book').addClass('hidden'); 

    books.find('.filter ul a.active').each( 
        function(){
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            books.find(selector).removeClass('hidden'); 
        }
    );        
  });
}
```

I've got a working demo of this in action here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/atImc

I believe I have to somehow alter the JS so it shows all "Blue Horror" books instead of all "Blue" books and all "Horror" books. Can anyone help explain how to do this? It would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HIeGx

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if($('.books').length){
    var books = $('.books');
    books.find('.filter ul a').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();                             
      $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
      books.find('.book').addClass('hidden'); 
      var selectors = ""; // Declaration
      books.find('.filter ul a.active').each( 
          function(){
              var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            selectors += selector; // Collecting
          }
      );  
      books.find(selectors).removeClass('hidden'); //Assign
    });
  }
});
```

Collect all selectors and remove class `hidden` after `each` statement

**Updated**

```
 if(books.find('.filter ul a.active').length < 1) {
        books.find('.book').removeClass('hidden');
```

Add this lines after

```
books.find(selectors).removeClass('hidden'); //Assign
```

*Full code* :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if($('.books').length){
    var books = $('.books');
    books.find('.filter ul a').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();                             
      $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
      books.find('.book').addClass('hidden'); 
      var selectors = ""; // Declaration
      books.find('.filter ul a.active').each( 
          function(){
              var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            selectors += selector; // Collecting
          }
      );  
      books.find(selectors).removeClass('hidden'); //Assign
      if(books.find('.filter ul a.active').length < 1) {
        books.find('.book').removeClass('hidden');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That works great! But is there a way to reset it once all filters are unselected as when you de-select all filters all the books remain `hidden`?

Comment: Thanks for this. But is there a reason why I can no longer view genres together (Horror and Fantasy) when a colour isn't selected? Is this to do with the collecting?